# Find the horizontal asymptotes

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find the asymptotes of

$$f(x) = \exp\left(\frac{3+4x^2}{2-6x}\right).$$

The vertical asymptote was a piece of cake and it's $\frac{1}{3}$.

The horizontal asymptotes is calculated as $x\to\infty$. I know the limit will be $0$, I just can't seem to be able to calculate it.

I tried dividing the numerator and denominator by $x^2$ but that doesn't help me. I got a zero in the denominator or after simplifying the fraction I got $\frac{2}{3}$.

I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Antonio, why did you edit it like that? Now it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You may have an easier time of it if you use L'Hopital's Rule on the expression in the exponent. Then you have the form $e^{-\infty}$ as $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: My professor doesn't let us use L'Hopital's rule unfortunately. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: It may be simpler to see if you divide top and bottom of the exponent by $x$. Then at the bottom we have something that approaches $-6$, and at the top we have something that blows up, so the exponent becomes very large negative.

Comment: @DanielWaleniak in that case use Andre's comment.

Comment: @DanielWaleniak: I edited the exponential to make it more clear the fraction is an exponent of the exponential function.

Comment: @André Nicolas when I use your method (I used $|x|$) I get $\frac{∞}{-6}$ and that implies an exponent of negative infinity. However the limit of that whole expression with e would be negative infinity as well, I think, which is not correct.

Comment: @DanielWaleniak: a positive number (greater than $1$) with an exponent tending toward negative infinity will go to $0$.

Comment: @ Clayton Alright. Thank you.

Comment: really, let the x in place. Otherwise with other formulas you could get $\frac\infty\infty$. Letting the x, you get $f(x) \approx \exp(-\frac2{3}x)$. This approch gives you even not-horizontal or not-linear asymptots.

Comment: $e$ to a large negative power is close to $0$. If this is not clear, note that $e^{-B}=\frac{1}{e^B}$.

Comment: @André Nicolas No, I wrote it down and it was clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hints: what is the first order approximation of $3+4x^2$ towards infinity ? what about $2-6x$ ?

Formally: factor by highest degree term on numerator and denominator. then evaluate the behavior at infinity.

Comment: I got $\frac {4}{0}$ in the exponent when I substituted x for infinity.

Comment: let x in place.

Comment: Would it be something like $\frac {0+4}{0-6x}$ in the exponent giving $ \frac{-2x}{3}$ which would make it converge to 0?

Comment: yep. $f(x) \approx \exp(-\frac2{3}x)$. This is a much stronger way to study asymptots. Could even be  not horizontal, or not linear.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the help.